# creating list with sharepoint remote provisioning

Tags: sharepoint-online, remote-provisioning

Could anyone please point to a manual on creating lists via remote provisioning. I am using sharepoint online. I just need to create custom list populated with defined in my code columns (let it be console application). I have definition of my list like: column1: name:somename, type: text, column2:date, type somedate, column description, type: Multiple Lines of Text, etc.
Where can I get some example?
 What I currently have doesn't work. I also have this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0u9SWWDfXCM. But now it's too difficult for me to pull out my task from it. 
 Thanks in advance.

```
using (var context = new ClientContext(webUrl))
{
    context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, password);

    var web = context.Web;
    context.Load(web, w => w.Title);
    context.ExecuteQueryRetry();

    var ptci = new ProvisioningTemplateCreationInformation(web);

    ptci.FileConnector = new FileSystemConnector(
        String.Format(@"{0}\\..\\..\\", 
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory), 
        "");
    ptci.ProgressDelegate = delegate(string message, int progress, int totalNumber)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0:00}/{1:00} - {2}", progress, totalNumber, message);
    };

    ptci.PersistBrandingFiles = true; 

    var template = web.GetProvisioningTemplate(ptci);

    var myCustomList = new ListInstance
    {
        Title = "My title",
        Url = "lists/mycustomlist",
        TemplateType = (int)ListTemplateType.CustomGrid,
        Description = "some description",
        EnableAttachments = true
    };
    template.Lists.Add(myCustomList);
}
```

Comment: You say it doesn't work, can you list any errors you are getting? I escaped your slashes, so that the formatting is right.

Comment: Also, have you tried this link? https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-Guidance/blob/master/articles/SharePoint-Add-In-Recipe-list-definition-template.md

Comment: There are lots if samples available in OfficDev/PnP which are about SP online and Hybrid scenarios, do checkout @ [OfficeDev](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples)